# 「勉強{べんきょう}を続{つづ}ける」 vs.「勉強をやり続ける」

Tags: word-choice

Do 「勉強を続ける」 and 「勉強をやり続ける」 have the same basic meaning: "to continue with one's studies"?

Is 「やり続ける」 a slightly rougher, less formal, way of saying「続ける」？ But, the difference in nuance is minimal at best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a hold of 2 native speakers. they pretty much agree with what i wrote. however, i learned you can also say "し続ける", and that "ず" and "づ are pronounced the same (can't image how romaji deals with "づ" and "ず).

Comment: づ and ず are both romanized as *zu* most of the time (because romanization is usually intended to reflect pronunciation, not kana), but in some schemes づ is *du*, and a few people still write *dzu*.